# Unable to change the default editor in the terminal

Tags: bash, vim

My default editor is [Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)) at my server. I use Bash and Linux.

I tried to change Vim to be my default editor unsuccessfully by:

```
echo vim > $EDITOR
```

How can I change Vim to be my default editor?

The following code does not work in file *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)*:

```
export EDITOR='vim'
```

Comment: What unix/linux are you using, and specifically what shell?  Bash, csh, other?

Comment: do you have vim installed? and if so is it on your PATH?

Comment: @Neil: I have Vim installed. It is apparently also in my PATH, since I can start vim by the command vim in Terminal.

Comment: Additionally, if you only wish to temporarily change the default editor for one command (for the case of git, not wanting to use vi) you can do `EDITOR=nano git commit --amend` or whatever the command happens to be, and `EDITOR` will be set to `nano` just for that command.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Adding

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

to your *.bashrc* file should really do the trick. (Quotes aren't necessary there and, depending on what quotes you used, they may be the cause for your problem.)

You must open a new shell (or enter `source ~/.bashrc` at the prompt) after modifying file *.bashrc* for the modification to take effect.

What is the program from which you want Vim to be started?

I haven't used Git, but [the documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) reads:

> The editor used to edit the commit log message will be chosen from the GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the core.editor configuration variable, the VISUAL environment variable, or the EDITOR environment variable (in that order).

So check whether one of these variables is set:

```
echo $GIT_EDITOR $VISUAL $EDITOR
git config --get-all core.editor
```

For me,

```
export VISUAL=vim
```

solved the problem.

Comment: @Jochen: The above command does not work. The program is Git from which I want vim to be started.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did using the VISUAL environment variable solve your problem?

Comment: echo $GIT_EDITOR $VISUAL $EDITOR gives me pico pico. How can I change these variables?

Comment: You can change them with
    export GIT_EDITOR=vim
    export VISUAL=vim
    export EDITOR=vim
(If the variable are already exported, you can omit the ``export´´).

Comment: I am on MacOs Mojave and i can confirm that i was having the problem of setting system default editor but this solution works beautifully i.e laravel tinker on edit mode

Answer (score 21):

You can use the Git configuration option *core.editor* to set the editor of your liking, e.g., [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano):

```
git config [--global] core.editor "nano"
```

You can also change this by editing the *.gitconfig* file in your home directory (global) or git repository (create it if it doesn't exist) if you don't have shell access:

```
...
[user]
  name = Your Name
  email = your@email.address
[core]
  editor = nano
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vim=/usr/bin/vim # Or wherever the Vim binary is
export EDITOR=vim
```

should do the job.

Comment: Your command does not work. I tried it also with $EDITOR unsuccessfully.

Comment: It has to be:
EDITOR=vim
export EDITOR
or if you use bash just
export EDITOR=vim

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an `EDITOR` environmental variable. My `.bashrc` file  does define this:

```
alias vi='vim'
```

And supposedly, if Vim can't find a file called `.vimrc` in your home directory, it runs in "compatibility mode" and you only get vi features until you say type `:nocp`.

If it is based on your `EDITOR` environmental variable, you would set it like this in Bash:

```
export EDITOR='vim'
```

Comment: You don't need an `EDITOR` environment variable to create one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer for the default editor. I keep the accepted answer as it is because the focus here is about Git and server side. Like setting its editor by variables `$GIT_EDITOR`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Since things have changed in Mac OS X, you will have to add the following in the *.profile* file in the base directory of the user:

```
export EDITOR='vim'
```

You can follow the following instructions:

1. open the terminal
2. Type `cd`  (hit <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this will take you to the base directory))
3. Type `echo "export EDITOR='vim'" >> .profile` (hit <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are done)
4. (Restart the terminal)

=========================

*Or* just type:

```
echo "export EDITOR='vim'" >> ~/.profile
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of these answers are helping me:

Here is what the Git documentation are saying, *[git-commit(1) Manual Page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)*:

> The editor used to edit the commit log
> message will be chosen from the
> GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the
> core.editor configuration variable,
> the VISUAL environment variable, or
> the EDITOR environment variable (in
> that order).

Here is the Bash [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) excerpt on export (brackets are optional):

```
export [-fn] [name[=word]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) to be your default history editor (which is why I'm here):

Edit file *~/.bashrc* and add

> set -o vi

anywhere in the file. Then all the lovely *vi* command history is available (<kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when setting up my new MacBook Pro.

**Here's how I solved it**

To switch to your editor of choice (say [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano)) on a MacBook you will need to add the following lines to your `~/.zshrc` file if your default shell is `zsh` or `~/.bash_profile` if your default shell is `bash`:

```
export EDITOR=nano
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

However, a simpler approach to do this will be to use the `echo` command to insert them into your `~/.zshrc` file if your default shell is `zsh`:

```
echo 'export EDITOR=nano' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export VISUAL="$EDITOR"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

OR `~/.bashrc` if your default shell is `bash`:

```
echo 'export EDITOR=nano' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export VISUAL="$EDITOR"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Run the command below to activate the new configuration:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

*Or*

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

If you need to switch to other editors of choice you can replace `nano` with your preferred editor:

- Vim - `vim`
- Vi - `vi`

That's all.