# Permanently set the default editor in Terminal

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, terminal

I have used this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647032/unable-to-change-the-default-editor-in-terminal) to set my editor in Terminal. Unfortunately it only sets for a single session which means every time I reopen Terminal I have to set it again.

**I would like to set it once and never have to do it again.** Just so you are aware, I'm using GNU Nano.

Thanks!

Comment: Sensibly enough — your question is not exactly programming related and it will feel comfortable after emigration to superuser.

Comment: Good point Michael. Indeed I debated it myself and am now clearler on the issue. Will try not to make the same mistake again.

Comment: It is beyond me, though, why is it voted for migration to serverfault and superuser. But being a server superuser myself I hardly know this fine line myself :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the command into your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: if Eric is using bash, that is.

Comment: He is probably using default for mac os x, which is bash.

Comment: @hacker Apologies. I didn't see that.

Comment: @gadgetmo, that's okay. I'm puzzled, tho, I thought you *know* he is *not* using osx :)

Comment: Guys, I'm using OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Comment: @EricBrotto, so that's more or less what I thought. So, you have two answers and both should work just fine.

Comment: Any idea where I could find this bashrc file? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: In your home directory. Like `nano ~/.bashrc` (or `nano ~/.profile` if you go Grady's way).

Answer (score 2):

I think, and I will be swiftly and pedantically corrected if I am wrong, but; putting that in your ~/.profile will be executed by any shell, ~/.bash_profile will be executed by bash
I generally only ever edit my .profile on Mac ,or my .bashrc on Linux...

From my understanding the difference between bashrc and bash_profile, is that the bashrc gets called for new interactive terminals or when you start bash... Even from bash, and bash_profile is called for login terminals...