# Editor does not open when prompted to enter commit message

Tags: macos, git, github

Apparently Git is suppose to open an editor for you when it wants you to enter a commit message. This never happens on my machine so I am wondering if it is just not set up or I don't have Vim or something. TextEdit is my default text editing (.txt) application.

How can I have Git open a text editor for me to use?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647032/unable-to-change-the-default-editor-in-terminal

Answer (score 2):

See [`man git-var`](http://git-scm.com/man/var) for explanation on how `git` finds an editor to start:

> The order of preference is the $GIT_EDITOR environment variable, then
>   core.editor configuration, then $VISUAL, then $EDITOR, and then the
>   default chosen at compile time, which is usually vi

I'd start with `export GIT_EDITOR=/path/to/your/editor` or `git config --add core.editor /path/to/your/editor`, to provide an editor which you know to be installed.

Comment: `git var -l` will list the current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

### To use *Nano* as the inline terminal editor (I'm on a Mac)

`git config --global core.editor "nano"`

### To use the *Sublime Text* Mac app

First add the path to the Mac App Sublime Text.app (where the bin subl is located) to your profile:
`echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile`

Test it by opening a new terminal then running `subl` in the terminal, the **Sublime Text** app should open.

### Add `subl` as your preferred text editor to your git profile

`git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`

### Test it to make sure Sublime opens it and do a small edit, save

`git commit --amend`

### View the change

`git log --oneline`

(Close and re-open the terminal if you are using Visual Studio Code with the embedded terminal)