# Breakpoint on a different folder in a Rails application doesn't work well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm debugging a Rails application that uses gems from my local environment. Is there a way to place a breakpoint in one of the gem's file and have it trigger when I debug my app ?

Comment: So it seems that the debug process does trigger as I get a REPL on the Debug Console, but none of the IDE bells and whistles like Call Stack / Variables state show up.

Answer (score 3):

[How can I see the source code of a gem installed on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145216/how-can-i-see-the-source-code-of-a-gem-installed-on-my-machine) should help you

If you need to edit the source code of say Devise, you would run:

`bundle open devise`

This will open the gem in your default text editor, allowing you to put breakpoints wherever needed.

Alternatively to see where it's stored on your machine try:

`bundle show devise`

Comment: I know how to browse my gem and add a breakpoint. My issue is that when it hits the line the debug process doesn't trigger properly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough with my question. I've added a comment underneath. Thanks for helping out anyway !

Comment: No worries, I think the standard REPL is the most you can get from a pry point inside an engine but not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gem 'pry-rescue'` and `gem 'pry-rails'` in your gemfile to debbug your code. Just put in your group development like this:

`group :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
end`

in your code you can put 
`binding.pry`

and after that just run your application and your request will stop where you put the binding.pry

Comment: Sure enough, but my intention is to sue the IDE's debugger :)